# Property or method "firstName" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I keep getting this warning for my inputs on my `Signup.vue` page. I have warning for all the four inputs in my code:

- `firstName`
- `lastName`
- `email`
- `password`

I keep getting this warning for each instance respectively.

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "firstName" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

```
---> found in
    ---> <Register> at src/components/Register.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

This is my `Signup` component

```
<template>
    <div id="register">
        <form>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" v-model="firstName"/>

            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" @v-model="lastName"/>

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" v-model="email"/>

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" v-model="password"/>

            <button type="submit">Register!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            form: {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                email: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        //methid take two parameters input or local parameter and the value of it 'firstname'-john
        updateForm (input, value){
            this.form[input] = value

            let storedForm = this.openStorage() //extract openstorage and place in storedform
                if(!storedForm) storedForm = {} //if no data, then make empty object

            storedForm[input] = value //store new value
                this.saveStorage(storedForm) //save changes in saveStorage function which is connected to local storage
        },
        mounted() {
            if (localStorage.name){
                this.name = localStorage.name;
            }
        },
        //opening local storage form
        openStorage(){
            return JSON.pasrse(localStorage.getItem('form'))
        },
        //saving local storage data
        saveStorage(){
            localStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(form))
        }
        
    },
    watch: {
        name(newName){
            localStorage.name = newName;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Comment: please show us the component. this mostly happens if you use a variable inside your template, but not have a reference in your script part.

Comment: you use `v-model="firstName"` but in your `data()` you have `return {form: {firstName, ...etc...}}`. so try `v-model="form.firstName"`. I also noted you have a `@v-model="lastName"`, I don't think it's correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

While rendering the view, Vue is unable to find the properties for each of your input `v-model`s, since the fields are in the form object. You can either refer to them as `form.firstName`, `form.lastName` etc or move them out of the object in the `data()` section.